# Set secomp to unconfined in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, seccomp

I need to be able fork a process. As i understand it i need to set the security-opt. I have tried doing this with docker command and it works fine. However when i do this in a docker-compose file it seem to do nothing, maybe I'm not using compose right.

## Docker

```
docker run --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined <id> dlv debug --listen=:2345 --headless --log ./cmd/main.go
```

## Docker-compose

### Setup

docker-compose.yml

```
networks:
  backend:

services:
  example:
    build: .
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.8

RUN go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
RUN dlv debug --listen=:2345 --headless --log ./cmd/main.go
```

command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build --abort-on-container-exit
```

## Result

> 2017/09/04 15:58:33 server.go:73: Using API v1 2017/09/04 15:58:33
>   debugger.go:97: launching process with args: [/go/src/debug] could not
>   launch process: fork/exec /go/src/debug: operation not permitted

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The compose syntax is correct. But the security_opt will be applied to the new instance of the container and thus is not available at build time like you are trying to do with the Dockerfile `RUN` command.

The correct way should be :

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM golang:1.8
RUN go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
networks:
  backend:

services:
  example:
    build: .
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "5002:5002"
    entrypoint: ['/usr/local/bin/dlv', '--listen=: 2345', '--headless=true', '--api-version=2', 'exec', 'cmd/main.go']
```