# OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python-3.x, keras, openblas

I am facing a problem now, unable to run any program in the cluster. It gives error.

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 64 current, 64 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 64 current, 64 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 64 current, 64 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 64 current, 64 max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello-world.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "/home/amalli2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/amalli2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import np_utils
  File "/home/amalli2s/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/amalli2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/amalli2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/amalli2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/amalli2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/amalli2s/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception
```

This problem, i assume to be same as this one [Multiple instances of Python running simultaneously limited to 35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256738/multiple-instances-of-python-running-simultaneously-limited-to-35)

So according to the solution when I set
`export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`

then I end up getting following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
Aborted
```

Is there anybody else facing same issue or has idea on how to solve this ? Thank you.

EDIT:
Ok, Seems like this happened because of some config restrictions the admins were trying to implement. Now it works again.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I had this problem running numpy on an ubuntu server. I got all of the following errors, depending on whether I tried to import numpy in a shell or running my django app:

- PyCapsule_Import could not import module "datetime" from
- numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ( OpenBLAS blas_thread_init:
- pthread_create failed for thread 25 of 32: Resource temporarily unavailable

I'm posting this answer since it drove me crazy. What helped for me was to add:

```
import os
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
```

before

```
import numpy as np
```

I guess the server had some limit for the amount of threads it allows(?). Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot

Comment: Thank you @Ylor and @Haramoz. For me it worked this solution when adding 
`import os`
`os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'`
 before importing pandas. All in my app.py file of my flask application

Comment: To add a bit more to this, the error above is commonly encountered when using multithreading in Python, alongside OpenBLAS. In their [FAQ](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/Faq#multi-threaded), OpenBLAS suggests this as a solution. [This](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki/Notes-on-Parallel-Processing-with-Python-and-ObsPy) post also has some useful information. Both of the above were cribbed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56113154/5843188).

Answer (score 12):

This is for others in the future who encounter this error.  The cluster setup most likely limits the number processes that can be run by a user on an interactive node.  The clue is in the second line of the error:

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 64 current, 64 max
```

Here the limit is set to 64.  While this is quite sufficient for normal CLI use, it's probably not sufficient for interactively running Keras jobs (like the OP); or in my case, trying to run an interactive Dask cluster.

It may be possible to increase the limit from your shell using, say `ulimit -u 10000`, but that's not guaranteed to work.  It's best to notify the admins like the OP.

Comment: I was also trying to run a Keras program interactively , when I faced the error. Then the cluster admin removed the restrictions and i was able to use it thereafter.

Comment: In my case,   
`OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 3 of 24: Resource temporarily unavailable


OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 4096 current, 1540106 max
`

Answer (score 9):

Often this issue is related to the limit number of processes available through `ulimit` (in Linux):

```
→ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127590
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096         # <------------------culprit
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

A temporary solution is to increase this limit:

```
ulimit -u unlimited
```

Most servers I've encountered have this values set to the number of pending signals. E.g. `ulimit -i`. So, on my example above I did instead:

```
ulimit -u 127590
```

Then, added a line on my `~/.bashrc` file to set it on login.

For more info on how to permanently fix this, check out: https://serverfault.com/a/485277

Answer (score 8):

Had this exact problem in Docker, it seems it's an issue with older versions.

In case anyone has this problem and cannot upgrade Docker version, the workaround I find is to add to the container run the following option

```
--security-opt seccomp=unconfined
```

Comment: For docker-compose, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033437/1061155

Comment: upgrading the docker version solved the issue for me

Answer (score 4):

If you are a manager, you can:

1. change temporarily the limit number of processes with the command `ulimit -u [number]`
2. change permanently the limit number of processes, i.e. the parameter `nproc` in `/etc/security/limit.conf`

If you are a user, you can:

1. In bash

```
    $ export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=2
    $ export GOTO_NUM_THREADS=2
    $ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
```

2. In Python

```
    >>> import os
    >>> os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1`
```

Then the problem due to multiple-threads in Python should be solved. The key is to set the number of threads to be less than the limit for you in the cluster.

Comment: This works from `bash terminal` but from jupyter notebook its still failing. I did set these environment variable using below script:


import os
os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS']='4'
os.environ['GOTO_NUM_THREADS']='4'
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS']='4'

Answer (score 2):

Building on Ylor's answer, rather than limiting yourself to a single thread, read through the error outputs (here are the first few lines of mine):

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 13 of 64: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 2048 current, 384066 max
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 58 of 64: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 2048 current, 384066 max
...
```

and find the minimum thread number which failed–then set the thread count to one fewer (12 for me here):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '12`
```

This will maximize your code's ability to use threads while still staying within current system limits (if unable to change).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Docker after upgrading image from nvidia/cuda:11.2.2-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04 to nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu22.04.
My docker version is 20.10.8. The problem was resolved after I upgraded the docker version or added the option below:

> --security-opt seccomp=unconfined

After research, I found that as of docker version 20.10.10, the default seccomp policy upgraded to support running containers based on recent versions of Fedora and Ubuntu: [20.10.10](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/20.10/#201010)