# Why would setting "export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1" impair the performance?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openblas

I try to set "export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1" as [this document](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example-rl-pong.html?highlight=openblas) suggests. But I found a strange phenomenon that setting this significantly impairs the performance of my RL algorithms(I've done some tests for TD3 and SAC, all results consistently indicate that "export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1" impairs the performance). Why would this cause such a big problem?

BTW, the algorithms are implemented using Tensorflow1.13, data are fed into the neural network through [tf.data.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset). all tests are done on [BipedalWalker-v2](https://gym.openai.com/envs/BipedalWalker-v2/) environment from OpenAI's Gym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linked guide suggests setting this variable specifically when using `ray`, not always.

AFAICS, that's because that framework itself spawns many processes (one for each actor or something), so each of them using multiple threads would bring no speedup. This is not the case when there's only one or only a few processes.

---

On a general note, [OpenBLAS FAQ](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/Faq) says that OpenBLAS' multithreading might "conflict" with the main program's multithreading and recommends setting `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` in such a case. The FAQ entry however fails to provide any details to verify its claim, so it can very well be obsolete! As per https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki/Notes-on-Parallel-Processing-with-Python-and-ObsPy, symptoms of such a "conflict" are rampant deadlocks and segfaults. So if you have nothing of the kind, you are in the clear. Major Python libraries are very responsible in dealing with such problem themselves rather than dumping them on the user, so I'm pretty sure that if OpenBLAS has any usage restrictions, `numpy` and `scipy` enforce them internally and automatically if you are using OpenBLAS through them.

Comment: Thanks for answering and sorry for responding late. I get the reason why they set it but I don't understand why setting this would impair the final performance of the RL algorithm. I thought it would only affect the training speed. Does it have something to do with that I have network update in a separate thread?

Comment: @SherwinChen OpenBLAS takes advantage of multiple threads to improve its performance (as you may know, many linear algebra operations are embarrassingly parallel). If you disable this feature, it will be degraded to single-thread performance.

Comment: Thanks for the update. According to your update, did you suggest that we no longer have to set `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`? BTW, I'm not so sure if we concur with the definition of 'performance'. When I set `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`, the score averaged over 100 episodes varies from 250-300 at the convergence. When I don't set this, the average score is pretty stable at 300. I don't understand why simply setting `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` would make such a difference.

Comment: @SherwinChen That goes without saying from your question! You said that it "impairs the performance" if set and didn't say that it "causes crashes" or anything if not set. So why should you set it then?)

Comment: Hi, I've updated my previous reply. I set it because I want to implement a distributed version of my algorithm using `ray`. And according to the document, I set it. Then I spot this confusing phenomenon.

Comment: @SherwinChen can't say for sure without [the means to reproduce the problem](/help/mcve). As I said, the library doc's justification is if there are lots of actively running threads on the system, at some point, switching and synchronization overhead becomes greater than the benefit from better CPU utilization. Most likely, your specific workload doesn't reach that point.