FastAPI fails spinning up worker
I am running FastAPI inside a docker container on my deployment VM. The image tests well on my develop OSX + Docker. Now, running it on the target machine it fails with the issue below.
It says max workers is -1?
[2024-04-20 23:26:12 +0200] [165] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0
[2024-04-20 23:26:12 +0200] [165] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (165)
[2024-04-20 23:26:12 +0200] [165] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2024-04-20 23:26:12 +0200] [166] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 166
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 1 of 2: Operation not permitted
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max

Here is my gunicorn_conf.py file
"""
GUNICORN CONFIG
"""
import multiprocessing
import os


workers_per_core_str = os.getenv("WORKERS_PER_CORE", "1")
max_workers_str = os.getenv("MAX_WORKERS", 2)
use_max_workers = None
if max_workers_str:
    use_max_workers = int(max_workers_str)
use_max_workers = 2
workers_per_core_str = "1"
web_concurrency_str = os.getenv("WEB_CONCURRENCY", None)

host = "0.0.0.0"
port = "8000"
bind_env = os.getenv("BIND", None)
use_loglevel = os.getenv("LOG_LEVEL", "info")

bind = "{}:{}".format(host, port)

cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
workers_per_core = float(workers_per_core_str)
default_web_concurrency = workers_per_core * cores
if web_concurrency_str:
    web_concurrency = int(web_concurrency_str)
    assert web_concurrency > 0
else:
    web_concurrency = max(int(default_web_concurrency), 2)
    if use_max_workers:
        web_concurrency = min(web_concurrency, use_max_workers)

accesslog_var = "/gunicorn.log"
use_accesslog = accesslog_var or None
errorlog_var = "/gunicorn.err"
use_errorlog = errorlog_var or None
graceful_timeout_str = os.getenv("GRACEFUL_TIMEOUT", "120")
timeout_str = os.getenv("TIMEOUT", "120")
keepalive_str = os.getenv("KEEP_ALIVE", "5")

I assume some settings on the target machine may be off?
Here is my ulimit output from the host
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7841
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7841
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

and inside the running container
ulimit -a
real-time non-blocking time  (microseconds, -R) unlimited
core file size              (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority                 (-e) 0
file size                   (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                     (-i) 7841
max locked memory           (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                          (-n) 1048576
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues         (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority                  (-r) 0
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) unlimited
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                          (-x) unlimited

Where should I look? Thanks!

Hello, did you check this thread, I think it is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026652/openblas-blas-thread-init-pthread-create-resource-temporarily-unavailable

Yes, I had found it but the solution there with ulimit didnt do it for me and my error says RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max . But maybe I should read deeper into the full thread. Thanks for pointing it out.

I worked around it, not solved. I reverted to a older docker image dependency based on Alpine instead of our reworked image based on Ubuntu 22. This seems to work for the relatively old VM setup we are running on. Thanks!
